# Connect MiniDv camcorder via USB C & Firewire or MiniDisplay port

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, displayport, video-capture

I'm looking to transfer MiniDv tapes to my 2017 Macbook Pro via a USB C connection. The camcorder has a Firewire 4-pin connection. Therefore I'll need a few converters in order to be able to import to my Macbook Pro. I'm wondering what adapters will work.

I understand that worst case I'll need a Firewire to Thunderbolt adapter and then a Thunderbolt to USB C adapter. I'm wondering if there might be cheaper option...

Would I be able to use [an adapter like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X2BZSS7) which is a **Mini DisplayPort to USB C** instead of the [$50 Apple Thunderbolt to USB C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MQ26QIY).

I know that Mini DisplayPort and Thunderbolt 1 inputs are the same shape, but will an adapter like I linked above be able to handle the transfer of video from my camcorder to laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FireWire is consumer grade and well supported, you have identified the least expensive manner of connecting. Thunderbolt 3 does use USB-C connector, but unless you are willing to use a usb capture card  or computer and pipe in HDMI, I would set aside USB adapters and stick with thunderbolt 3 to 2 adapter and then the thunderbolt 2 to FireWire adapter. All from Apple.

- [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MMEL2AM/A)
- [Apple Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter](https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MD464LL/A)

With tax and shipping that’s under $80 in USA.

Comment: Renting a FireWire Mac or paying someone to transfer can also be cheaper than finding these adapters if you don’t need them.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that worst case I'll need a Firewire to Thunderbolt adapter and then a Thunderbolt to USB C adapter.

No.  You will need a Firewire to Thunderbolt adapter and then a [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344119/119271).

USB-C is only the connector *type*, it’s still a Thunderbolt port.

You can’t use a mini DisplayPort cable because you’d be missing the Thunderbolt signaling.  Yes the, the physical connectors are the same, it doesn't mean all the connector pins are there.  Remember, DisplayPort is a component signal/protocol of Thunderbolt.  In other words, a a Thunderbolt cable will support mDP, but an mDP cable doesn’t support Thunderbolt.