# Can a USB-C to mini DisplayPort cable be used with USB-C to Thunderbolt ports?

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, displayport

I have the above cable for my current set up of sending display from my PC laptop with a USB-C port to my 2010 iMac with a mini DisplayPort port. It works great.

I have now bought a mid-2011 iMac that does not have a mDP port. It has a Thunderbolt port. Which I guess is Thunderbolt 2.

The current cable is not working with this new set up (even though it will plug into the Thunderbolt port) and I cannot work out if the problem is trying to use the cable itself or if I am not setting it up properly.

So do I need a different cable if the only thing that is changing in the configuration is that instead of a mini DisplayPort on the iMac, I have Thunderbolt port on the iMac.

From other answers I think I might need a different cable but I still can’t quite work out what, or if I need one of those very expensive apple adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic rules about Thunderbolt and DisplayPort cables:

- Any Type C Thunderbolt 3 cable is also a USB-C cable.  Only *quality* USB-C cables are also Thunderbolt 3 cables.  In other words, avoid cheap ones.
- Thunderbolt 1 and Thunderbolt 2 cables, while they carry the mDP signal are *not* mini DisplayPort cables.  [mDP cables are not Thunderbolt cables](https://blog.tripplite.com/whats-the-difference-between-thunderbolt-and-mini-displayport) and vice versa.
- Thunderbolt cables can only be used on Thunderbolt ports.
- mDP cables can be used in either mDP ports or Thunderbolt ports

<sub>Source:  [TrippLite.com](https://blog.tripplite.com/whats-the-difference-between-thunderbolt-and-mini-displayport)</sub>
[image: Thunderbolt/DisplayPort Quick Ref Guide]

> So do I need a different cable if the only thing that is changing in the configuration is that instead of a mini DisplayPort on the iMac, I have Thunderbolt port on the iMac.

Yes.  The 2011 iMac (27" only) support [Target Display Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389348/119271) via Thunderbolt only.  You will need the following:

- [Thunderbolt 1/2 cable](http://radnex.us/Apple-Thunderbolt-Cable-1M)
- [Thunderbolt 3 to Legacy Thunderbolt Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344119/119271)

The 2011 iMac is a very different animal compared to the 2010 that uses DisplayPort.  To connect to it via Target Disk Mode, it requires a TB connection. So you'll need a proper adapter and cable to make this work.