# Connecting Apple Silicon Mini to Apple Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt-display, apple-silicon

I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display ([APPLE 27" THUNDERBOLT DISPLAY 2560X1440 MC914LL/B A1407](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407208/connecting-apple-silicon-mini-to-apple-thunderbolt-display/407210#407210)) and ordered an M1 Mini.

I'm trying to figure out if they will work together, and if so, what cables are required.

Comment: See this answer for details on connecting Thunderbolt devices:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405330/119271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter, e.g. [this one](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) from Apple.

Comment: @ICT1901 Got the same setup here, works fine :-)